# Rmarkdown add hyperlink to figure caption to github_document

Tags: r, r-markdown, markdown, github-flavored-markdown, github-document

I am writing up a README file for a github repository, and I would like to add hyperlinks to some words in a Figure Caption.

I haven't managed to do so using neither `knittr::include_graphics` with fig.cap , `![Caption has [words](link.com)](image.png)` nor `<a href="link.com">target="Caption"</a>` inside the text syntaxes.

On top of that, there are also citations in the same caption.

Here's the last thing I tried, using C# syntax inside the rmd regular syntax (paragraphs added to make reading easier here):

```
![Global-scale bioclimatic congruence map to analyse environmental 
mismatches between recently updated bioclimatic databases 
<a href="www.worldclim.org/version2" >target="WorldClim v.2"</a> ,
MERRAclim  [@c.vegaMERRAclimHighresolutionGlobal2017], 
<a href="www.chelsa-climate.org" >target="CHELSA"</a>, 
and ocean databases <a href="www.marspec.org">MARSPEC</a> 
and <a href="www.bio-oracle.org" >target="Bio-ORACLE v. 2.0"</a>](inst/figures/README-congruence.png)
```

I also tried using regular text syntax inside a chunk using knitr (again, no paragraphs in the actual code):

````
```
{r eval=T, echo=FALSE, fig.cap="Global-scale bioclimatic congruence map
 to analyse environmental mismatches between recently updated bioclimatic
 databases [WorldClim v.2](www.worldclim.org/version2), 
 MERRAclim [@c.vegaMERRAclimHighresolutionGlobal2017], 
 [CHELSA](www.chelsa-climate.org),
 ocean databases [MARSPEC](www.marspec.org)
 and [Bio-ORACLE v. 2.0](www.bio-oracle.org)"}

knitr::include_graphics("man/figures/README-congruence.png")

```
````

The caption I want looks something like this:

> Global-scale bioclimatic congruence map to analyse environmental
> mismatches between recently updated bioclimatic databases [WorldClim
> v.2](https://www.worldclim.org/version2), MERRAclim (C. Vega, Pertierra, & Olalla-Tárraga, 2017),
> [CHELSA](https://www.chelsa-climate.org), [MARSPEC](https://www.marspec.org) and [Bio-ORACLE v. 2.0](https://www.bio-oracle.org).

Comment: Following, looks like this might not yet be supported. https://github.com/rstudio/rmarkdown/issues/2385

Comment: Will update if this seems like a good answer/workaround, but playing now with **captioner** https://github.com/adletaw/captioner/blob/master/vignettes/using_captioner.Rmd